# passing complex object to a service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

i have to pass two complex `objects` and a `Marker`(***google map marker***) to a service, i know that i can use

```
intent.putExtra(name,value);
```

But i didn't find any example for my problem.

I know that i have to implement `Parceable` or `Serializable`for the two complex objects , but for the Marker, what i have to do?

Can someone provide me an example?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what service are you using?

Comment: Diffent types of `Service` have different type of extras that you can send back to the main UI thread. You need to be more specific about your `Service`. It's unclear what type of `Service` you are using.

Comment: @BlaShadow i' m using a Class that extends `Service`

Comment: @CKDPublishing i' m using a Class that extends `Service`

Comment: what your service need to use a class like that?

Comment: i need to do some  stuff with the marker and another objects, when is required,and activity stay in foreground.

Comment: What exactly do you need from the Marker object that you have to pass to the service? Do you need the position? The title? etc? Just pass each item you need individually via `putExtra`.